# angularjs code is not working after grunt build

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I am having this problem and unable to find any answer which fix the problem.

I have created small Angularjs code with grunt build system.

Bower.json
http://pastebin.com/8AScfd7d

Gruntfile.js
http://pastebin.com/e0d7QLGG

log.txt (grunt --force)
http://pastebin.com/MYk9iR53

index.html
http://pastebin.com/B48w0Z58

using grunt --force command to build.

When I run the build it does not show any errors in console and under netowek tab all script loads fine but nothing happens. If I replace the minified script tag (my custom code) with the source script it start working.

Running out of ideas what could be wrong.

Comment: You are using grunt as a server?  Why not use nodejs?

Comment: I am not using grunt as a server, I am using grunt to create build from source

Comment: "force, -f A way to force your way past warnings." Maybe try without, and see what errors it throws?

Comment: It may help to minify a subset of files, and starting to re-add files to minification list until you get the silent failure mentioned in your question to find exactly where the issue is occuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced ngMin with ngAnnotate in Gruntfile.js and also added 'ngAnnotate:dist' in grunt build task.

```
/*ngmin: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
      src: '*.js',
      dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
    }]
  }
},*/
ngAnnotate: {
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
                        src: '*.js',
                        dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```